# mysql Alter table to compress data fails with "Duplicate entry"

Tags: percona, mysql5.6

I was trying to compress few tables, but one of them caused this error

> alter table MY_table row_format=compressed, algorithm=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE; 
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>   ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '740003820' for key 'PRIMARY

Then tried same with

> alter table MY_table row_format=compressed;

Got same error 1062 Duplicate entry.

According to DOC 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html

> When running an online ALTER TABLE operation, the thread that runs the
>   ALTER TABLE operation will apply an “online log” of DML operations
>   that were run concurrently on the same table from other connection
>   threads. When the DML operations are applied, it is possible to
>   encounter a duplicate key entry error (ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate
>   entry), even if the duplicate entry is only temporary and would be
>   reverted by a later entry in the “online log”. This is similar to the
>   idea of a foreign key constraint check in InnoDB in which constraints
>   must hold during a transaction.

What are my options?

Comment: I'd advise to either isolate this in transaction so you compressing the table are the only one modifying it or enabling the `LOCK`

Comment: FYI. We chose to stop replication and run the alter, we did it one server at time...